# Day not selected when bound to kendo UI datepicker control in angular application

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-datetimepicker

I am using kendoUI datepicker control in my angular 7 application.  At the moment I am trying to bind json date returned by the api to the datepicker control. The code below does the job but shows only the month and year. It doesnt show the exact date. So I need to see the date selected when the datepicker control is selected. Is there a better an easier way to do that.

The dateformat what i get in json is /Date(1224043200000)/

UI

```
<kendo-datepicker *ngIf="EditMode"
  [format]="'MMMM yyyy'"  (valueChange)="dateFoundedChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="FirmDetails.Firm.DATE_FOUNDED" [value]="dateFoundedDate">
</kendo-datepicker>
```

Component code

```
  get  dateFoundedDate(): Date {
         var dateString = this.FirmDetails.Firm.DATE_FOUNDED;
         var seconds = parseInt(dateString.replace(/\/Date\(([0-9]+)[^+]\//i, "$1"));
         var date = new Date(seconds);
         return date;


   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using date picker format as below:

```
[format]="'MMMM yyyy'"
```

try to add date inside the format as follow:

```
[format]="'DD MMMM yyyy'"
```

You **don't need** to add **[format]** in your code, datepicker will load the default time format.

Refer following links:

[Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/stevescotthome/kKhm3/5/)
[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/krustev/64ZXd/)

Comment: As i mentioned in my post i am getting date in json date format which i need to decode. Secondly I dont want to show the date when the datepicker loads. I just need to show the month and year. Its only when the datepicker is selected that it should show the date